# Using LINQ to query four nested entities. - Include Where condition

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have four classes Offer, Section, Field, and Option:

Where the offer has sections and every section has some fields and each field has some options as shown:

```
    public class Offer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    }

    public class Section
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class Field
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; } //[question, group]
        public ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Option
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to get the offer by id including the nested entities and this code works perfectly:

```
    var offer = _context.Offers
        .Include(o => o.Sections
            .Select(s => s.Fields
            .Select(f => f.Options)))
        .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == offerId);
```

The problem is when I try to filter the Fields by 'type' like this:

```
    var offer = _context.Offers
        .Include(o => o.Sections
            .Select(s => s.Fields.Where(f => f.Type == "question")
            .Select(f => f.Options)))
        .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == offerId);
```

and I get this error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
>   Parameter name: path

I've reviewed lots of questions and still cannot achieve that :(

[Linq: query with three nested levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044255/linq-query-with-three-nested-levels)

[EF LINQ include nested entities [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096194/ef-linq-include-nested-entities)

[Using LINQ to query three entitites. - Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427008/using-linq-to-query-three-entitites-include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-n)

Comment: _context.Offers
        .Include(o => o.Sections).ThenInclue(s=>s.Fields)
            .Select(s => s.Fields.Where(f => f.Type == "question")

Comment: I think ThenInclude method is only in EF Core and not with .NET Framework

Comment: True, what is your expected result?

Comment: I want to filter the fields where the filed.type = "questions":not get all fields

Comment: how to achieve what you wrote in your first comment but with .Net framework

Comment: How about if you try `var offer = _context.Offers.Include("Sections").Include("Sections.Fields").Include("Sections.Fields.Options").Where(i => i.Sections.Any( s => s.Fields.Any( f=>f.Type == "question"))).FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == offerId);`?

Comment: @SelimYıldız It works but it doesn't consider the where clause and it gets all fields even if the type not equal to "question"

Answer (score 1):

Include() is used for Eager loading. It is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query, so that we don't need to execute a separate query for related entities. Where() is currently not supported inside Include.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just filter the result you can do something like this :

```
        var offer = _context.Offers
         .Include(o => o.Sections
         .Select(s => s.Fields
         .Select(f => f.Options)))
         .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == offerId);
        var filtered_offer = 
        new Offer
        {
            Sections = offer.Sections.Select(S => new Section
            {
                Id = S.Id,
                Name = S.Name,
                Fields = S.Fields.Where(f => f.Type == "question").ToList()
            }).ToList(),
            Id = offer.Id,
            Name = offer.Name
        };
```

Comment: I get this error bro: The entity or complex type 'Tadawlat.RequestsDb.Offer' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.